# When is a scala partial function not a partial function?

Tags: scala, function, functional-programming, partial-application, partialfunction

While creating a map of String to partial functions I ran into unexpected behavior.  When I create a partial function as a map element it works fine.  When I allocate to a val it invokes instead.  Trying to invoke the check generates an error.  Is this expected?  Am I doing something dumb?  Comment out the `check()` to see the invocation.  I am using scala 2.7.7

```
def PartialFunctionProblem() = {
    def dream()() = {
        println("~Dream~");
        new Exception().printStackTrace()
    }
    val map = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,()=>Unit]()
    map("dream") = dream()      // partial function
    map("dream")()              // invokes as expected
    val check = dream()         // unexpected invocation
    check()                     // error: check of type Unit does not take parameters 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  When I replaced my dream() calls with dream()_ it behaved as I expected.  I'll go out and read more on PartialFunctions so I don't misuse the term again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For convenience, Scala lets you omit empty parens when calling a method, but it's clever enough to see that the expected type in the first case is `()=>Unit`, so it doesn't remove all the parens for you; instead, it converts the method into a function for you.

In the `val check` case, however, it looks just like a function call result getting assigned to a variable.  In fact, all three of these do the exact same thing:

```
val check = dream
val check = dream()
val check = dream()()
```

If you want to turn the method into a function, you place `_` after the method *in place of the argument list(s)*.  Thus,

```
val check = dream() _
```

will do what you want.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the problem is that you got it all wrong. :-)

Here are some conceptual mistakes:

```
def dream()() = {
    println("~Dream~");
    new Exception().printStackTrace()
}
```

This is not a partial function. This is a curried method with two empty parameter lists which returns `Unit`.

```
val map = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,()=>Unit]()
```

The type of the values in this map is not partial function, but function. Specifically, `Function0[Unit]`. A partial function would have type `PartialFunction[T, R]`.

```
map("dream") = dream()      // partial function
```

What happens here is that Scala *converts* the partially applied method into a function. This is not a simple assignment. Scala does the conversion because the type inferencer can guess the correct type.

```
val check = dream()         // unexpected invocation
```

Here there's no expected type to help the type inferencer. However, empty parameter lists can be ommitted, so this is just a method call.